# How to use apply functions on multiple columns in groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
df.dropna(subset=["home_team_goal_timings","away_team_goal_timings"]).groupby("home_team_name")[["home_team_goal_timings","away_team_goal_timings"]].apply(lambda x: ",".join(x).split())
```

I grouped the data by the column `home_team_name` I want to group aggregate data for two columns. This returns [home_team_goal_timings,away_team_goal_timings] for every group. It works fine if you use some aggregate function such as sum on some other attribute. How can you make it work for apply?

Comment: `df.dropna(subset=["home_team_goal_timings","away_team_goal_timings"]).groupby("home_team_name")[["home_team_goal_timings","away_team_goal_timings"]].agg(lambda x: ",".join(x).split())`?

Comment: Yes that works, Thank you.

Comment: Therefore the apply function only works if you send one column?